# Can infinite union of finite sets be finite?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Intuitively, I can say **no!** Because just look at following **example:** singleton sets $\{ n\}$ where $n \in \mathbb N$ and their infinite union $\cup_{n\in \mathbb N} n$ is infinite.

My question is can I find finite sets whose infinite union is finite?

Comment: Yes, consider $\displaystyle \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \lbrace 1 \rbrace$.

Comment: Must the sets be distinct?  $\{1\}\cup \{1\}\cup \{1\}\cup \{1\}\cup \cdots$ is clearly going to equal $\{1\}$ and is finite.

Comment: If they are all distinct the answer is no, but if you don't give this restriction it may be finite.

Comment: You are certainly right however I should have added I want them to be distinct.

Comment: This is actually an interesting problem: prove that if an infinite union is finite, then there must be a repeat set in the union.

Comment: If the sets must be distinct, then a handwavy argument you can make for a direct proof is that since there are only finitely many subsets of $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ we will repeatedly eventually always see a new largest number in the union regardless what we have seen thus far and however long we had been going.  The union will thus contain this infinite sequence of "former largest seen numbers" and thus be infinite.  This can of course be formalized.

Comment: Ignore what I said... @eyeballfrog's suggested proof is far simpler.

Comment: Each of the unioned sets is a subset of the union result, and a finite set has only finitely many subsets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elaborating on the comments by eyeballfrog and Karl:

Let $(X_i)_{i\in I}$ be an infinite family of sets, and assume their union $U 
= \bigcup_{i\in I} X_i$ is finite. Now for each $i\in I$, $X_i\subseteq U$. Since $U$ is finite, it has only finitely many subsets. By the pigeonhole principle, since $I$ is infinite, there are $i\neq j$ in $I$ such that $X_i = X_j$.

Thus (taking the contrapositive), the union of any infinite family of pairwise distinct sets is infinite.

Answer (score -1):

Denote some set of finite "collections" by $C$ and call the general union $U=\bigcup C$ the set of "underlying elements". $C$ shall be infinite in the sense that there is an injection $i\colon {\mathbb N}\to C$.

Denote the range $\{1,\dots,k\}$ of the first $k$ naturals by $R_k$. If $i[R_k]$ denotes the set holding the first $k$ distinct finite collections from $C$, then the finite union of finite sets $\bigcup i[R_k]$ is always a finite subset of $U$.

From $k$ or less underlying elements, we may form not more than $2^k$ collections. So the union $\bigcup i[R_{2^{k+1}}]$ is a finite set containing at least $k+1$ underlying elements.

Now if $U$ were finite, then $2^{|U|+1}$ were a natural and $\bigcup i[R_{2^{|U|+1}}]$ would be a subset of $U$ holding at least $|U|+1$ elements.

Comment: This seems far more complicated than it needs to be. In particular, you don't need to identify "infinite" with "injection $\mathbb{N}\to C$" (which requires the axiom of choice). The pigeonhole proof in my answer does not use choice.

Comment: @AlexKruckman I don't need a mathematical principle to read the word "infinite" as the injection existence. And I don't choose elements out of infinitely many collections anyhow. If I can always select $n\in{\mathbb N}$ sets from $C$ (whatever the $n$), then the hypothesis that $|\bigcup C|$ is a natural lets you find some index at which you get into trouble. Not complicated in my view.

Comment: I suppose you're free to read the word "infinite" however you want. I'm just pointing out that the standard definition is "not finite", i.e., not in bijection with a natural number, and the theorem that every infinite set has an injection from $\mathbb{N}$ is not provable in ZF set theory. It's true this is pedantic, since the equivalence is provable in ZFC. But I thought someone who owns the domain name axiomsofchoice.org and seems to have some interest in constructive mathematics would be open to a bit of AC-related pedantry :)

Comment: @AlexKruckman I don't think we can count it as pedantry if the post makes the language explicit - you're not given a pedantic correction. All it gets us is a downvote, as you can see. I'm sure I can point you to nice texts that define infinite as injection existence, especially in constructive texts. And there the pigeonhole principle would need some machinery as well. Now even if we were to dislike the reading, given the finiteness assumption of $|\bigcup C|$, we don't need to go all that much higher.